# Is this native code possible for further static analysis?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

I was trying to reverse engineer a native lib code in an android app. the `.so` contains many functions. But the function `sUQWWyTBEs()` was referred in the Java code. I was curious how this function works.

**This function returns a string like this `47fjlkj843h9asjklj94kljfsad93j4l2715943hasd...` but what I wanted is that how this value was generated or returned.**

the code of the function `sUQWWyTBEs()` decompiled with `Ghidra`:

```
*************************************************************
                             *                           FUNCTION                          
                             *************************************************************
                             undefined  __cdecl  Myapp_sUQWWyTBEs()
             undefined         w0:1           <RETURN>
             longlong *        x0:8           param_1
                             Myapp_sUQWWyTBEs XREF[2]:     Entry Point (*) , 00101350   
        00100e44 08  00  40  f9    ldr        x8, [param_1 ]
        00100e48 01  00  00  b0    adrp       x1, s_c7a584936712f32773d3d0a_00101000           ; = "c7a584936712f32773d3d0a"
        00100e4c 21  60  08  91    add        x1, x1, #0x218
        00100e50 02  9d  42  f9    ldr        x2, [x8, #0x538 ]
        00100e54 40  00  1f  d6    br         x2
```

in my understanding, I have made the static analysis as like following:

`00100e44 08  00  40  f9    ldr        x8, [param_1 ]`

load the value at memory address param_1 into register x8.

`0100e48 01  00  00  b0    adrp       x1, s_c7a584936712f32773d3d0a_00101000`

sets register x1 to 0x101000.

`00100e4c 21  60  08  91    add        x1, x1, #0x218`

adds 0x218 to x1, so it sets x1 to 0x101218.

`00100e50 02  9d  42  f9    ldr        x2, [x8, #0x538 ]`

loads the value at x8 + 0x538 into x2.

`00100e54 40  00  1f  d6    br         x2`

and finally branches to the  address stored in `x2`.

with that being said, Here I don't know the memory at address at `x2`, obviously it initially  depends on the value `param_1` holds. is there way or how can I refer where `param_1` was initialized? I don't know very much about usage of `Ghidra` or other reverse engineering tools. any one might help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this function is declared on the Java side as a `native` function, `param_1` is a `JNIEnv*`. The [Android JNI documentation states](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html):

> JNI defines two key data structures, "JavaVM" and "JNIEnv". Both of these are essentially pointers to pointers to function tables.

The code you show thus basically calls the function in the function table at offset 0x538. Assuming you're showing a 64-bit Android program, function pointers are 8 bytes so you need to figure out the 167th function pointer (starting from 0).

Take your copy of `jni.h` and extract the members of `struct JNINativeInterface`, number them starting from 0:

```
0:     void*       reserved0;
1:     void*       reserved1;
2:     void*       reserved2;
3:     void*       reserved3;
4:     jint        (*GetVersion)(JNIEnv *);
...
167:     jstring     (*NewStringUTF)(JNIEnv*, const char*);
```

So, assuming I did not make any mistakes, the code you are showing calls `env->NewStringUTF` with `s_c7a584936712f32773d3d0a_00101000+0x218` as argument.

I think you can let Ghidra parse jni.h to make those types available. If you then change the type of `param_1`, that might be sufficient to let Ghidra do this mapping for you and produce a sensible decompilation to C/C++.

Comment: there is a memory address `101218` which is the value of now `x1` contains. the `101218` memory address holds the String in which the function returns I mentioned in the above. But I wanted to learn how was possible to return this string. furthermore I have loaded the library into JEB decompiler. JEB highlights every instruction's output in a comment Here is the output of JEB decompiler ( https://pastebin.com/AUSyXN0j ). Thanks

Comment: Then presumably x2 points to the (part of the) string that JEB says it points to. I cannot possibly help you if I don't have the information you have. If this answer does not solve your question, please point out what it is missing or what your actual requirements are. What do you mean by "learn how it was possible to return this string"? The bytes appears to simply be embedded in your program code at that offset, and the `NewStringUTF8` call turns it into a Java `String` object.

Comment: Thank you for your info, as I understand in your reply the `param_1` holds the jniENv.

Comment: the `x2` points this function (code snippet shared here: https://pastebin.com/Hc2vB46C ), in that function shares same code of the previous but JEB output in comments are somewhat different, for example at the very first instruction: in the comment it refers to other functions notably this line `Java_com_mode_myapp_myotherFunction13+10h / 538h` what is offset `538h` is it the NewStringUTF(), which one is it refering?

Comment: I have no idea how your disassembler arrived at that conclusion. I would treat it as a false positive. Unless your binary happens to have a call or reference to this function at byte 0x538, which would be a *gigantic* coincidence.

Comment: in JEB, I got this line when double clicked `538h`: `.dynsym:00000000'00000538   ptr_Java_com_mode_myapp_myotherfunction dq offset Java_com_mode_myapp_myotherfunction `

Comment: That means it's a publicly visible symbol. Pure coincidence that that appears on that offset.

Comment: still for learning this, where is 167 come from in your answer above? I am reffereing to "function pointers are 8 bytes so you need to figure out the 167th function pointer (starting from 0)." in your answer. thanks

Comment: 0x538 = 1336 = 8 * 167

Comment: and where do I look the function pointers?

Comment: the actual values of the function pointers are irrelevant, a they point to your Android implementation of the JNI functions. It is sufficient to know what JNI function is called and to know what it does.